# How to Dynamically Populate a Selection Box in Jenkins with JSON Files from Bitbucket?

Tags: json, bitbucket, cicd

I'm working on a Jenkins pipeline and I want to create a selection box that dynamically populates with JSON files stored in a Bitbucket repository with develop branch. Based on this JSON selection, I will run next step which is target my JSON file.

Here's what I'm aiming for:

> 1. Fetch the list of JSON files from a specific Bitbucket repository.
> 2. Populate a selection box in Jenkins with these JSON file names.
> 3. Allow Jenkins build executor to select one of these files as input for the pipeline.

I've been exploring options like using the Bitbucket API or Jenkins plugins, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Can anyone provide guidance or a sample script to achieve this? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware of one of the major restriction of Jenkins - [it is not able to load the parameters until the build starts](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-41929). Any change to the list of parameters and/or their possible values will be only applied after the build is triggered, which is, basically, unwanted and even dangerous for any serious use.

So, to work this around, there are basically only two ways (not counting switching from Jenkins to another CI/CD tool):

- usage of custom parameter types with plugins such as [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) and [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) plugins;
- usage of workarounds that don't require custom parameter types.

From my experience, the custom parameters give some great flexibility in theory, but this also comes with some drawbacks:

- they are extremely difficult to use even for simple cases as you have to write and maintain tons of complex Groovy scripts;
- these scripts may be subject for admin approval, and all of them have to be carefully verified so that they don't get approved access to sensitive Jenkins internal APIs - which makes it unfeasible for large environments;
- they may have (and if fact usually have) unresolved security vulnerabilities;
- the pipelines could not be reused on another Jenkins instance bolt-on.

So I came up with a simple solution based on the information I've learned from the long discussions under the Jenkins Jira issues related to the issue mentioned above. It relies only on the existing Jenkins pipeline features and doesn't require any dependencies.

First, I define a stage that reads the parameter values from a file within a workspace and defines the parameters dynamically using a combination of declarative and scripted syntax. Note that there is `Abort on parameter change` parameter dedicated for future control of the build behaviour:

```java
stage('Update the job parameters') { 
    steps {
        script {
            def jobParameters = readJson file: 'job_parameters.json'

            properties([
                parameters([
                    choice(
                        name: 'Some choices',
                        description: 'Select from these choices',
                        choices: jobParameters.someChoices
                    ),
                    // all your parameters go here
                    string(
                        name: 'Some value',
                        description: 'Define this value',
                        defaultValue: jobParameters.someDefaultValue,
                        trim: true
                    ),
                    booleanParam(
                        name: 'Abort on parameter change',
                        description: 'Enable to update the build parameters',
                        defaultValue: false
                    )
                ])
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

You can make this even more flexible and put the whole parameter definitions to that (or other) file, use YAML files with `readYaml` instead of JSON, or add a `git` step to check out a different repository that contains the parameters. For example, I use this to populate the parameters with the values from Ansible inventories.

Then, I define the conditions when the execution of the job should be stopped due to the change of the parameters. Basically, Jenkins should do it for the first build in every new branch, and optionally anytime by our wish. It also makes sense to add `beforeAgent: true` to avoid wasting the resources. You can add other conditions, as well, but these are the minimum for the safe usage:

```java
stage('Abort the build due to the change in parameters') {
    when {
        anyOf {
            expression { env.BUILD_NUMBER == '1' }
            expression { params.'Abort on parameter change' }
        }
        beforeAgent: true
    }
    steps {
        script {
            currentBuild.result = 'NOT_BUILT'
            currentBuild.displayName = 'marked as not built to update the parameters'
            currentBuild.description = """
                I also add a meaningful description here with all the handy links 
                so that the users see it on build status page and just 
                click the rebuild link with no worries or questions.
            """.stripMargin().stripIndent().trim()
            error "Job parameters were updated - please check ${env.BUILD_URL} and re-run the build"
        }
    }
}
```

`currentBuild.result = 'NOT_BUILT'` ensures that the parameters update does not make the build statistics worse - the build will not get marked as failed and the build weather remains unaffected.

This script can also be moved to a shared library and reused anywhere.

The only drawback is that you have to rerun the build sometimes - but it literally takes seconds if you add the correct links and comments to the description.

More important is that this approach is safe for the builds that could be triggered automatically. And in this case, you still have control and you can schedule the build with some other parameters right from the same stage using `build` step.